# LAN connection issue

Tags: networking, lan

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I am having issue with the LAN connection. I am connecting my Laptop to switch with LAN. Whenever I am restarting Laptop, LAN cable does not connect. I need to connect my Laptop with another LAN port. There is no issue with cable because when I connect my Laptop with another switch port with same cable, it's get connected and than I connect my Laptop with same cable & same port and now it's get connected. Kindly help to diagnose the root cause.